# What is the timestep in Keras' LSTM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have some troubles with the LSTM implementation in Keras.

My training set is structured as follow:

- number of sequences: 5358
- the length of each sequence is 300
- each element of the sequence is a vector of 54 features

I'm unsure on how to shape the input for a stateful LSTM.

Following this tutorial: http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/, I've created the subsequences (in my case there are 1452018 subsequences with a window_size = 30).

What is the best option to reshape the data for a stateful LSTM's input?

What means the timestep of the input in this case? And why?

Is the batch_size related to the timestep?

Comment: Here 300 is your timestep. Basically you have 5358 samples 300 timesteps each having 54 features

Comment: So I can use data with shape (5358,300, 54) if I don't create subsequences, right? But if I do it? And how the batch_size works in this case?

Comment: Those tutorials with windows are really the worst way to start learning an LSTM. Batch size is the number of sequences you're passing to the model for one gradient descent update.

Comment: Assuming you really want windows, and your calculation of 1452018 subsequences is correct, your data shape is `(1452018,30,54)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm unsure on how to shape the input for a stateful LSTM.

```
LSTM(100, statefull=True)
```

But before using stateful LSTM ask yourself do I really need `statefull` LSTM? See [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/understanding-stateful-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) and [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/32581/54387) for more details.

> What is the best option to reshape the data for a stateful LSTM's
>   input?

It really depends on the problem on hands. However, I think you do not need reshaping just feed data directly into Keras:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(300, 54))
```

> What means the timestep of the input in this case? And why?

In your example timestamp is 300. See [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-timesteps-lstm-networks-time-series-forecasting/) for further details on timestamp. In the following picture, we have 5 timestamps that we feed them into the LSTM network.

[image]

> Is the batch_size related to the timestep?

No, it has nothing to do with batch_size. More details on batch_size can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/153535/103634).

---

Here is simple code based on the description that you provide. It might give you some intuition:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.keras import Input, Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.python.layers.core import Dense

x_train = np.zeros(shape=(5358, 300, 54))
y_train = np.zeros(shape=(5358, 1))

input_layer = Input(shape=(300, 54))
lstm = LSTM(100)(input_layer)
dense1 = Dense(20, activation='relu')(lstm)
dense2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense1)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, ouputs=dense2)
model.compile("adam", loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=512)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, the timestep is the lenght of the subsequence to consider, am I right? Why you set the timestep equal to the sequence length?

Comment: Maybe I was a bit inaccurate but, just to clarify my problem, each sequence is independent.

Comment: @maccN timestamps and sequence length both are the same things. 300 timestamp is not too much for LSTM to learn. If I were in you just use stateless LSTM.

Comment: The sequence represents the position of some points extracted from each frame of a 10-second video. I thought stateful LSTM can perform better than stateless LSTM for this task.

Comment: See here for advantage and disadvantage of stateful and stateless https://machinelearningmastery.com/understanding-stateful-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/